# Convert method to a generic method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to convert this method to generic form. I'm not able to do so because of the properties of the object.

```cs
private async Task<T> GetSalesforceMachineData<T>()
{
    T machineData = await CallSalesforceApi<T>();
    while (!machineData.done)
    {
        var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(machineData.nextRecordsUrl);
        T nextData = await GetNextData<T>(encodedUrl);
        machineData.done = nextData.done; //not able to convert because of these properties
        machineData.nextRecordsUrl = nextData.nextRecordsUrl;//not able to convert because of these properties
        machineData.records.AddRange(nextData.records);//not able to convert because of these properties
    }
    return machineData;
}
```

something like this

```cs
private async Task<T> GetSalesforceMachineData<T>()
{
    T machineData = await CallSalesforceApi<T>();
    while (!machineData.done)
    {
        var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(machineData.nextRecordsUrl);
        T nextData = await GetNextData<T>(encodedUrl);
        machineData.done = nextData.done;
        machineData.nextRecordsUrl = nextData.nextRecordsUrl;
        machineData.records.AddRange(nextData.records);
    }
    return machineData;
}
```

Comment: 2 options; either add a generic constraint to an interface or base class that implements those properties, or pass delegates to select the values. The latter would probably be over cumbersome in this example, considering there are 3 values to select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics are not the same as templates - the compiler needs to be able to statically resolve the members you're using for all possible `T`, known and as-yet unknown. One way to do this would be to define an interface (or base type) that *has* those members, make all of the required types *implement* that interface (which should usually be as simple as adding `: IYourNewInterface`, since the members presumably already exist on the public API, assuming they're not naked fields), and add `where T : IYourNewInterface` to the generic method.